# app delegate swizzling is disabled remote notifications

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I want to make a phone verification with Firebase, but I get a failure to send a notification. I'm sharing `AppDelegate` code. I couldn't figure out what I had to do? I performed certificate insertion. `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` is value `no`

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
  print(remoteMessage.appData)
}

func registerForPushNotifications() {
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    .requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, error in
      print("Permission granted: \(granted)") // 3
    }
  }

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: {_, _ in })

    // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
  } else {
    let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
  }

  application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
  FirebaseApp.configure()      
}
```

**Code send function**

```
func sendCode(_ sender: Any) {
  let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Phone number", message: "Is this your phone number? \n \(emailField.text!)", preferredStyle: .alert)
  let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in
    PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(self.emailField.text!, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in
      if error != nil {
        print("eror: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
      } else {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(verificationID, forKey: "authVID")
      }
    }
  }

  let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
  alert.addAction(action)
  alert.addAction(cancel)
  self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: what you have done for push notification certificates?

Comment: Yes, I added it seamlessly. It works when I send a notification with Firebase.

Comment: ok and what payload you are sending?

Comment: I added it to the subject.

Comment: Are you using Cloud Function to send notification?